# AWK alias not printing

Tags: bash, awk

The below awk command (copied and pasted from stackoverflow) works fine from the command line but doesnt print anything when aliased

```
 awk '/WORD/ {print $3}' log.log | awk 'BEGIN{c=0} length($0){a[c]=$0;c++}END{p5=(c/100*5); p5=p5%1?int(p5)+1:p5; print a[c-p5-1]}'

alias getperc="awk '/WORD/ {print \$3}' log.log | awk 'BEGIN{c=0} length(\$0){a[c]=$0;c++}END{p5=(c/100*5); p5=p5%1?int(p5)+1:p5; print a[c-p5-1]}'"
```

I am fairly new to using bash. What am I missing here?

Comment: show the correct definition of your alias, i.e. `alias myAlias="...."`. \ In any case, aliases are a very limited tool. Research how to install your awk script as a function instead. Good luck.

Comment: `awk` piped into `awk` usually indicates a problem; you should have only one `awk`, probably.  And using an alias means you can't change the file name that's scanned, so an alias isn't very flexible — you'd do better with a script (or a function if you're really going to exercise it often enough for speed to matter, but that's incredibly unlikely to be the case in my view).

Comment: Unbackslashed `$` in double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use aliases. They require an additional layer of quoting, which is troublesome (as here), and they prevent you from being able to usefully parameterize or add conditional logic to your code.

A simple transliteration to a function is:

```
getperc() { awk '/WORD/ {print $3}' log.log | awk 'BEGIN{c=0} length($0){a[c]=$0;c++}END{p5=(c/100*5); p5=p5%1?int(p5)+1:p5; print a[c-p5-1]}'; }
```

A slightly more capable one, which will still use `log.log` by default, but which will also let you provide an alternate input file name (as in `getperc alternate.log`) or pipe to your function (as in `cat alternate.log | getperc`):

```
getperc() {
  [[ -t 0 || $1 ]] || set -- - # use "-" (stdin) as input file if not a TTY
                               # ...this will let you pipe to your function.
  awk '/WORD/ {print $3}' "${1:-log.log}" | awk 'BEGIN{c=0} length($0){a[c]=$0;c++}END{p5=(c/100*5); p5=p5%1?int(p5)+1:p5; print a[c-p5-1]}'
}
```

Comment: now that's pretty neat... may turn me into a believer of functions. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there is confusion by bash regarding $3  and $0 it thinks they are argument of the alias. you can verify this by
try this in bash

```
alias ech="echo {print \$3}"
```

it will print just

> {print }

but now try

```
alias ech="echo {print \$\3}"
```

it will print what you expected

> {print $3}

Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: Not arguments *of the alias*, exactly. You'll note that an alias defined with `alias t=$'printf \'1=%s\n2=%s\n\' "$1"'` will print `1=` and `2=hello` when called with `t hello`, showing that `$1` was empty despite an argument being explicitly passed. It's rather expanding `$1` and `$2` in the context of the calling interactive shell, where these are almost universally empty unless someone's run something like `set -- one two` previously.

Comment: yes Charles I was wrong in that point it is not argument of alias.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  but the solution / root cause was right . what is your opinion on that ?

Comment: That the root cause was right is a fact, but it's not a fact I particularly happen to have an opinion about.

Comment: After a few moment's thought, though, I've managed to form an opinion:  While my position on aliases could be boiled down to an argument that they're almost never an appropriate tool, inasmuch as this answer is every bit as much about correct escaping of content inside double-quoted strings as it is about aliases, it's teaching something useful and is a helpful addition to the site.

Comment: That said, I'd tend to suggest `alias ech='echo {print \$3}'` (with single-quotes, not double-quotes) as a simpler solution -- or, if one needs to be able to nest literal single-quotes, `alias echo=$'echo \'{print $3}\''`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have tried this on my Linux Mint 18 I suppose it must be same for any bash system. with Single and  Double quotes and it worked fine both times. So my question is why do you prefer single over double quotes. I see that some of default alias they have with single quotes. So I think it more like a standard practice rather than rule. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The meanings are different. With `alias foo='echo "$bar"'`, the `$bar` is evaluated at the time when the alias is run; by contrast, with `alias foo="echo \"$bar\""`, (1) you had to add backslashes to escape your quotes, and (2) `$bar` is evaluated when the alias is created, *not* when the alias is run.

Comment: Now, yes, you can escape your `$` inside double quotes, but in single quotes that's not necessary: The `$`, **and the backslash preceding it**, are literal. Thus, there's less difference between the code as you run it directly and the code as you write it in an alias with single quotes. Fewer changes that need to be made -> fewer things to go wrong.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for clarifying. I had tried both the examples  1. foo='echo $bar' 2. foo="echo $bar" 3. foo='echo \"$bar\"'  and I now agree with your preference of single quotes clearly. I feel like answering this question, I got this clarity which otherwise I would not have got. Hope this comment chain be helpful for those who will visit this question to get more clarity.